# Cannot access site from PC via Windows or Ubuntu

Tags: dns, internet-connection, website

I have been unable to access a social network site: vk.com, since yesterday evening. At first I thought maybe it's just some virus or hosts problems etc, but I've checked everything and it's fine, and all other sites are working normally. I cannot get access, not from Windows 8.1, nor Ubuntu on the same PC. So it shouldn't be a virus or problem with the OS.

I also tried other browsers too: the same story, doesn't work. But I was able to visit the site with no problem from a Android phone and it uses the same Wi-Fi router. Also, I can access via proxy server by using TOR or some other free services like hide.me

DNS server is working I can define IP address via `$ ping vk.com`:

> PING vk.com (87.240.131.118) 56(84) bytes of data.

... but no reply.

I live in the UK and according to ping my access IPs via DNS are:

> 87.240.131.118, 87.240.131.117, 87.240.143.241, 95.213.11.129

but I cannot ping them too, though I can ping other vk.com IPs which are working for other countries, for example some of these: https://db-ip.com/all/87.240.156

So, this cannot be a problem with a virus, browser, OS or connection because I tried using Windows and Ubuntu and it works via proxy. It cannot be a problem with the provider or the router either, because I can access it fine with my phone.

Probably this is something with DNS servers by default, but I added Google DNS 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4 with no luck so far. Any ideas?

Comment: Try running ipconfig /flushdns in windows.

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot get access to it"? Is the error that the site does not exist or does not respond? If the latter, then the site has banned your IP for some reason: the fact that you can access through a proxy reinforces this surmise. It needn't be your fault: if your router has picked up a public IP released by a previous site user whose activity was deemed inappropriate, then you are unfortunately paying the penalty, but the remedy is simple: disconnect and reconnect your router and check that you have a different IP, then notify the site owner of the problem with the old IP.

Comment: @AFH This is a big social network, I doubt that they ban some IPs, and anyway I have static IP from my provider so restart didn't help.

Comment: OK, but you still haven't explained what you mean by "I cannot get access to it". It is puzzling that Androids work on the same network. Is your PC dual-boot, or is one OS a VM, in which case the network interface would be common to both? You should check if your Internet Security software has blocked the site. If Ubuntu is a VM, boot a Live CD and see if you can access from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it can not have anything to do with DNS. We could only blame DNS if lookup doesn't translate to correct IPs. I did ping the four IP's and all answers to ping. BTW, google dns doesn't agree with your isp. the *.118 is not included.

I suggest you do a trace route to see where your pings are filtered. My wild guess is already at your ISP.

Answer (score 1):

I am also unable to access that website from the UK so your equipment is probably fine. Out of curiosity, are you with Virgin Media? VM are currently experiencing issues routing to certain websites (e.g. imgur.com) so this could be related.

Comment: yes, I have Virgin Media, but it might be just a coincidence because I can access via phone through the same wifi router. If it's just a provider problems it will pass with time. I hope.

Comment: Hmm, how strange. And you are definitely browsing over WiFi, not 3G/4G on your mobile?

Comment: 100%, my 3G pay as you go tariff is too expensive for browsing

Comment: I just checked on my mobile and see that VK has it's own app - are you using that or going to vk.com via the browser? It's possible that the application connects to different domains which are working fine.

Comment: Yes you're right, I was using app and it also doesn't work through phone browser. So app is using some other address. Hm, probably it's just ISP problems. I can try to trace route like Frank suggested.